# SIunitx and non-integer exponents

Tags: siunitx, chemistry, number

I'm going through a number of old documents where I used `siunitx` to display numbers in scientific notation with non-integer exponents, like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num{e8.2}
\end{document}
```

(a very common way to write equilibrium constants in chemistry)

Unfortunately, with TeX Live 2021 those documents can't be recompiled as is, because newer `siunitx` seems unable to process non-integer exponents, so I have to fall back to:

```
10^{\num{8.2}}
```

Is there a more elegant to do that within the `siunitx` package? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm a chemist and I can't think of every seeing equilibrium constants given this way: it would be very had to compare them.

Comment: It may vary from country to country, then. But here (France), the strength of an acid is typically described with its pKa, so that its acid dissociation constant is written 10^{-pKa}, where pKa is usually a non-integer value.

Answer (score 1):

The exponent part of a number in `siunitx` was always intended to be  an integer, for use with SI prefixes. In v2, the fact this was not enforced was more-or-less an oversight. If you need values with non-integer exponents, you can format them yourself

```latex
\num[parse-numbers = false]{10^{8.2}}
```

which is of course essentially just math mode (`$10^{8.2}$`) but with the font control set up.

Comment: Non-integer exponents make comparison of values very tricky: I am _very_ reluctant to add this back in

Comment: Writing non-integer powers of 10 is a very common occurrence in my field of teaching, so knowing that this feature will not be coming back to siunitx is useful information. I'll just write my own macro. Is there any drawback to a one-line macro like `\newcommand{\powerten}[1]{\ensuremath{10^{\num{#1}}}}` ?

Comment: As for your first suggestion with `parse-numbers = false`, I just tried it and it doesn't produce the expected result. My siunitx is configured for French output (where the decimal separator is a comma), and with your suggestion the point is no longer replaced automatically with a comma. Hence the macro I suggested above.

Comment: @Miyase I was about to make a suggestion about a custom command: from your comment under the question, the `10` isn't really part of the value, it's part of the presentation of the value (a pKa is by definition a log10 value, so adding the `10` back in is not altering the value, rather how it's displayed).

Comment: Yes, that'd be a correct way of looking at it. I'll go with a macro, then. Thanks.