# SIunitx and non-number exponents

Tags: siunitx

I would like to use latin symbols in the exponents in siunitx. The question is simular to:
[SIunitx and non-integer exponents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638614/siunitx-and-non-integer-exponents)

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath,xfrac}

\sisetup{
    per-mode=fraction,
    fraction-function=\tfrac
}

\begin{document}
\unit{\per \second \per \pascal\tothe{n}}
\unit{\per \second \per \raiseto{n}\pascal}
\end{document}
```

Both versions do not work.

The output is not so important, because it does not work at all, but the results may look like, depending on the `fraction-function=\tfrac|\dfrac|\sfrac` as well as the `per-mode=fraction|power-positive-first`, like this:

[image]

This is used in combustion/gasification chemistry of solids to make a list of `n_i` exponents for different reactants of global reactions, eq. Coal+O2, Coal+H2O, or Coal+CO2.

*Is there a way to enable non-number exponents?*

Thx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thank you.

Comment: How do you want the compiled result to look like?

Comment: @DariaBogatova I added some information.

Comment: You don't have to complicate your work with the package SIunitx, you can write the units direcly: `${1\over {\rm s}\,{\rm Pa}^n}$` or `${}^1\!/_{{\rm s}\,{\rm Pa}^n}$` or `${\rm s}^{-1}\,{\rm Pa}^{-n}$`.

Comment: @wipet As much as you love classical TeX, you must admit that it is slightly harder to centrally control your notation using that syntax.

Comment: Of course, you can create a macros for units used in the document and write only macro names in the document.  And it is slightly harder to master the notation of dozens LaTeX packages than classical TeX syntax.

Comment: @wipet Well, most users have adopted the abstract LaTeX layer, which suggests that they do not agree with you. `;-)`

Comment: @wipet thank you for your examples. Of course, you can write plain tex or macros. But I do have more cases in my work which are similar to the stated example. So I would like to have just a working *siunitx* package. Which would be great.